# Change plastic bands in chair?

Tags: repair, plastic

How can I change these plastic *backing* strips in this chair?

I have another chair exactly like this one, but the white plastic strips are broken.

[image]
[image]

Comment: why don't you examine the broken strap to see how it is attached?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got to pull the band toward you when you're at the edge of the chair and get some slack where the band goes around the frame. Then use a screwdriver to gently pry the band out of the slot on the frame. If it's an old band there's a chance it will break when you try to pry it out. If you're successful then do the other side. Installing them is just the reverse. Good luck/

Comment: Thanks. Where can I buy these plastic bands? I tried searching by keyword but didn’t find anything.

Comment: Lowes sells a roll of plastic band but it has a different mounting method. You might be able to trim the edge similar to the one you remove. here's the link:  https://www.lowes.com/pd/elemental-Strap-Repair-Kit/1000372259

Comment: Seems like cutting the band for removal would be a lot easier if complete replacement is the goal.

Comment: @JPhi1618 I think/thought he wanted to use the ones shown for another chair.

Comment: @JACK, Ah, good point.  The ol' mix and match routine is great for repairs.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do this for someone once.  Jack is correct.  I don't know where they got the bands, but I found that if you soak them in boiling water for a few minutes, they become much more plyable and then tighten up as they cool down.